# Is there a better way to restyle REBOL VID modal dialogs?

Tags: rebol, rebol2

I would like to restyle the modal dialogs in REBOL2's VID, such as `alert`, `request/ok`, etc, so that they better fit with the theme of the rest of my application. The only way I've found to do this is to include my own altered version of the `request` function, substituting my own values into the layout in it. Is there any way to restyle these popups without having to redefine the `request` function?

The default popup vs an example result of what I'm looking for:

[image: default REBOL VID dialog]
[image: restyled version of REBOL VID dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regrettably, as far as I know there isn't.  I've had this problem myself in the past.  The only way to do it, is as you said.  Of course, that's fairly trivial since you can simply do: `source request`, copy it and make your changes.  Request and the other modals are wrapped in functions, which act as a black box around the internal code which generates the face and then feeds it to inform.

Comment: This is my experience too. It's a shame the layout code for each dialog isn't stored in the system/view object somewhere, but it's not.

Comment: I hoped that wouldn't be the case, but alas. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Your welcome.  And @rgchris, I agree that probably would have been better.

Answer (score 1):

Learned a simpler method from another REBOLer (thanks Gregg!). If you only need to change the background color and the enter/cancel buttons, this works as well:

```
svv/vid-face/color: 26.150.219
stylize/master [
    btn-enter: btn white
    btn-cancel: btn white
]
```